# Python 3.9 installed but not integrated (shown with) with Jupyter Notebook or Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, updates

I have installed (upgraded) Python 3.9.7 (latest version) for my project. My team is using this updated version. I was earlier having 3.8.8 which is still being shown in Jupyter Notebook. When I open the Terminal using Visual Studio code, it shows version 3.9.7.

I am pretty confused...there are two versions installed for Python. Please note that Anaconda navigator also shows 3.8.8 installed... How can I solve and have only single version (ie 3.9.7 installed on my machine)

[Command prompt version check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5SrF.png)

[Anaconda navigator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kk7i.png)

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjoHz.png)

Comment: How did you install Python 3.9.7? Your best bet is probably to clean up all the various Python installs, and stick to using Conda environments.

Comment: I have uninstalled the Anaconda all together and installed miniconda, and then separately  installed Jupyter notebook using conda install command. It is all very confusing... Preparing proper working setup in Jupyter and Anaconda for python... ;-(

Comment: *By the way @AMC. I installed Python 3.9.7 by downloading from official python.org link